# Chocolate molds in shapes of kitchen supplies

Tags: equipment, candy

I am going to be making a gag gift for some friends. I want to make chocolates in the shape of pots, pans, and cooking utensils as they are in the process of closing on a new house. I have no issues finding spoon, fork, or knife molds. Where I am having issues is the pots, pans, turners (like for flipping burgers) and spatulas. Does anyone know where I can find something like I am looking for? I know they will be smaller than the cutlery, and that is fine.

Comment: You may actually want to migrate this question to Arts & Crafts! While your end goal is to make a food item, the equipment (a specific mold shape) may not be on-topic for Seasoned Advice (as we rarely mold our own equipment) ... especially if you'll need to end up making or modifying a candy mold to get the shapes you want. Just a thought :)

Comment: I tried asking there earlier today but the question was closed as they only help with questions about issues during the actual process of making things.

Answer (score 1):

You can try placing your post, pans, turners and spatulas upside-down on some parchment paper, and spraying with non-stick cooking spray. Then, carefully pipe not too runny *(and not too dense)* melted chocolate over them, making sure to keep the part closer to the bottom of the pan thicker than the parts closer to the edges, as the chocolate will slide down to the edges eventually.

That will be all if the handles are conveniently flat and metal, otherwise you'll need mold the handles separately and attach them to the main part when both parts are cooled.

Comment: That only works if you want full size items, which would end up having to be thick to be strong enough. As the OP wants a selection of items, that ends up being a huge amount of chocolate

Comment: @ChrisH Just trying to lift up the giftee's day :)

Comment: Use toy items. (I have just seen the pans we used to play with as kids.)